# Unable to launch Selenium Web Driver on AWS lambda

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I try to launch Selenium web driver using Chrome but get such error:

`Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:45189`

Here is my code:

```
    public string FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var driver = CreateLambdaChromeDriver();
        driver.Url = "https://www.wikipedia.org";
        var html = driver.PageSource;

        return html;
    }

    public ChromeDriver CreateLambdaChromeDriver()
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        // Set the location of the chrome binary from the resources folder

        // Include these settings to allow Chrome to run in Lambda
        options.AddArguments("disable-gpu");
        options.AddArguments("headless");
        options.AddArguments("window-size=1366,768");
        options.AddArguments("no-sandbox");

        return new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: You are trying to run the server on lambda? I'm not sure if that is possible. Do you have any reference which indicates that you can do this?

Comment: @Marcin there are a lot of articles how to do that: https://medium.com/@Moatazeldebsy/ui-testing-using-selenium-webdriver-and-chrome-inside-aws-lambda-77a17ec64862

Comment: Thanks. Interesting use of lambda:-)

Comment: Check IP address of localhost it may be wrong.  From cmd.exe >Ping localhost